# Template overloaded = operator works in one class and fails to compile in another?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I made a small custom array container List a while ago and it works fine, this is how I overload its '=' operator:

```
List<T>& operator=(const List<T>& other); //in List.h


//in List.inl
    template<typename T>
    List<T>& List<T>::operator=(const List<T>& other)
    {
        _size = other._size;

        if(_size < _capacity)
        {
            _capacity = _size;
            _AdaptCapacityChange();
        }

        for(uint i = 0; i < other._size; i++)
        {
            _data[i] = other._data[i];
        }

        return(*this);
    }
```

However, now that I do the same in another class:

```
PointIndices<T>& operator=(const PointIndices<T>& point); //in PointIndices.h
//in PointIndices.inl
        template<typename T>
        PointIndicess<T>& PointIndices<T>::operator=(const PointIndicess<T>& point)
        {
            indices[0] = point.indices[0];

            return(*this);
        }
```

it doesn't highlight PointIndices and the operator keyword stays blue, and the compiler gives me: **Error   2 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int**

In both cases I've included the .inl file properly, the rest of the methods of PointIndices work fine, only the operator one gives me an issue.However in List, the same overloaded operator works fine.I'm confused, what could be causing this?

EDIT: requested testcase:

Header:

```
    template<class T>
    class PointIndices
    {
        public:
            PointIndices();
            PointIndices(T P1);
            virtual ~PointIndices();

            PointIndices<T>& operator=(const PointIndices<T>& point);

            T P1() const;
            T& P1();

        protected:
            T indices[1];
    };
#include "PointIndices.inl"
```

INL File:

```
    template<typename T>
    PointIndices<T>::PointIndices()
    {
        indices[0] = 0;
    }

    template<typename T>
    PointIndices<T>::PointIndices(T P1)
    {
        indices[0] = P1;
    }

    template<typename T>
    PointIndices<T>::~PointIndices()
    {

    }

    template<typename T>
    PointIndicess<T>& PointIndices<T>::operator=(const PointIndicess<T>& point)
    {
        indices[0] = point.indices[0];

        return(*this);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T PointIndices<T>::P1() const
    {
        return(indices[0]);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T& PointIndices<T>::P1()
    {
        return(indices[0]);
    }
```

Comment: You writing C++ or PHP? (`$index`)?\

Comment: sorry, I changed it for easier reading, however $ is allowed in Visual Studio, so it's ok

Comment: is that a copy/paste-error: `PointIndicessTx>&`?

Comment: for which line will it fail? can you provide a small testcase that we can paste and try?

Comment: yes, when I pasted it the automatic feature of the site moved everything a few tabs to the right, so while moving it back I must have erased something, edited it now

Comment: On what line is the error? What is `indices` and how is it declared? Are there any other error messages? How do you call this operator? How are the variables used in the assignment declared?

Comment: If the typos (`PointIndicessTx` and `PointIndicess`) are present in the real code, then that's probably the problem. Otherwise, please post the exact code you're compiling.

Comment: Off-topic, but if you really must decorate your names with underscores, then don't make them start with an underscore and a capital (like `_AdaptCapacityChange`). Names like that are reserved.

Comment: @DEIMOS: The site did not move anything. Those indendations are from your code.

Comment: look at @MikeSeymour 's comment : there's an extra _s_ at the end of `PointIndices` in a couple of places in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare a class template `PointIndices`, but misspell it in the function definition:

```
template<typename T>
PointIndicess<T>& PointIndices<T>::operator=(const PointIndicess<T>& point)
//          ^ extra "s" here                                   ^ and here
```